# Theorem 20.1 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, metric-spaces, solution-verification, proof-explanation

> Let $X$ metric space with metric $d$. Define $\overline{d}:X\times X\to \Bbb{R}$ by the equation $\overline{d}(x,y)=\min \{d(x,y),1\}$. Then $\overline{d}$ is a metric that induce the same topology as $d$.
>
> **Proof:** now we note that in any metric space, The collection of $\epsilon$ balls with $\epsilon \lt 1$ forms a basis for the metric topology, for every basis element containing $x$ contains such an $\epsilon$ ball centered at $x$. It follows that $d$ and $d^\prime$ induce the same topology on $X$, because the collection of $\epsilon$ balls with $\epsilon \lt 1$ under these two metrics are the same collection.

Honestly I don’t understand the proof. Before you say I am stupid(which I’m), here’s what I know: $B_d(x,\epsilon) =B_{\overline{d}}(x,\epsilon)$, if $\epsilon \lt 1$ and $B_{\overline{d}}(x,\epsilon)=X$, if $\epsilon \geq 1$. The inequality $\overline{d}(x,y) \leq d(x,y)$ and theorem 20.2 shows that $\mathcal{T}_{\overline{d}}\subseteq \mathcal{T}_d$. How to show $\mathcal{T}_{\overline{d}}\supseteq \mathcal{T}_d$? I think the most natural approach is to use lemma 13.3. Let $B_d(y,r)$ and $x\in B_d(y,r)$. Since ball is open in metric space notion, $\exists \epsilon \in (0,1)$ such that $B_d(x,\epsilon) \subseteq B_d(y,r)$. Since $\epsilon \lt 1$, $x\in B_d(x,\epsilon)=B_{\overline{d}}(x,\epsilon)\subseteq B_d(y,r)$. **Is this proof correct?**

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But the proof by Munkres is simpler.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Can you please explain his proof?

Comment: "Before you say I am stupid(which I’m)" You might not be _used to_ this kind of thinking yet. You might not know all the fundamental definitions of topology and analysis completely by heart just yet. You might not have all the basic results ready at your fingertips just yet. That doesn't in any way mean that you're stupid. It just means you're new.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for encouraging words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General fact: if $X$ is a set and we have two topologies $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}'$ on it, and $\mathcal{T}$ has a base $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{T}'$ has a base $\mathcal{B}'$, then $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{B}'$ implies $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{T}'$.

This is what Munkres means by that having the same base means having the same topology. The proof is immediate from definitions. But if you're sadistically minded, you can check lemma 13.3 for two inclusions, but you don't need it (a set is open iff it's a union of base sets etc.)...

He applies this to $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{T}_d$ and $\mathcal{T}'=\mathcal{T}_{\bar{d}}$, taking

$\mathcal{B} = \{B_d(x,r) \mid x \in X,0 <r< 1\}$ and
$\mathcal{B}' =\{B_{\bar{d}}(x,r) \mid x \in X, 0 <r< 1 \}$

Using the general fact he mentions in the first line, applied to both $d$ and $\bar{d}$:

> If $(X,\rho)$ is any metric space, $\mathcal{B} = \{B_\rho(x,r) \mid x \in X,0 <r< 1\}$ is a base for $\mathcal{T}_\rho$.

Proof: if $O$ is open in $\mathcal{T}_\rho$ and $x \in O$, there is some $r'>0$ so that $B_\rho(x,r') \subseteq O$. But define $r = \min(\frac12, r') < 1$ and note that $B=B_\rho(x,r) \in \mathcal{B}$ and $x \in B \subseteq B_\rho(x,r') \subseteq O$ so that we've verified $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $\mathcal{T}_\rho$ and we're done.

As the defined collections $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}'$ are identical,  the first fact finishes the proof.

QED. This is Munkres' argument in unnecessary detail.

Comment: I didn’t notice “ If $(X,\rho)$ is any metric space, $\mathcal{B} = \{B_\rho(x,r) \mid x \in X,0 <r< 1\}$ is a base for $\mathcal{T}_\rho$“ fact at all.

Comment: @user264745 do you see that it’s a reformulation of the first sentence?

Comment: Yup. Now every sentence of Munkres proof make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then a set $A\subset X$ is open if and only if it can be written as the union of open balls with radius smaller than $1$. In fact if $A$ can be written as the union of open balls, then it is written as an union of open sets, and therefore it's opn. And, if $A$ is open, for each $a\in A$, there is some $\varepsilon_a\in(0,1)$ such that $B_d(a,\varepsilon_a)\subset A$ and then$$A=\bigcup_{a\in A}\{a\}\subset\bigcup_{a\in A}B_d(a,\varepsilon_a)\subset A,$$and therefore $A=\bigcup_{a\in A}B_d(a,\varepsilon_a)$.

Now, if $d$ is any metric, if $\overline d=\min\{d,1\}$, and if $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, then $(\forall a\in A):B_d(a,\varepsilon)=B_{\overline d}(a,\varepsilon)$. Since in $(X,d)$ and in $\left(X,\overline d\right)$ the open balls with radius smaller than $1$ are the same, it follows from what I wrote in the first paragraph that the open sets of $(X,d)$ and the open sets of $\left(X,\overline d\right)$ are the same sets.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer.

Let $X$ be a metric space with metric d that induces a topology $\tau.$

The $U \in \tau,$ i. e. open in $X$, if for every

$z \in U$ we have an $\epsilon>0$ s. t.

$B_{\epsilon(z)}(z) \subset U$, where

$B_{\epsilon(z)}(z) =\{y| d(z,y) <\epsilon(z) \}. $

If $\epsilon_z \ge 1$ choose an $\epsilon'_z <1;$

Obiously $B_{\epsilon'} \subset B_{\epsilon}$
$(d(z,y) <\epsilon'$ implies $d(z, y) <\epsilon). $

So wlog you can assume $\epsilon <1$.

Can you finish?

Comment: Yes. I got the main idea of this proof.

Comment: Was not sure if this was the point of contention. Thought of deleting the post. But maybe it adds a little bit to  our understanding (yours and mine:)))

Comment: It definitely adds something. Don’t delete this(your) post.

Comment: Nice to hear that:))) Thanks.